# How to print the values of a symbolic tensor in tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am using tensorflow2.0. The code I am using is this:

```
f_1 = ConvLSTM2D(filters=25, kernel_size=(1,1), input_shape=(None,None,25,1,3), return_sequences=True)(expand_x1)
f_1 = f_1[:,:,:,0,:]
```

I want to see the f_1 variable. So I converted it into a NumPy array but get this error: "Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (strided_slice_4:0) to a numpy array." It can not convert a symbolic tensor f_1 into an array. Now how can I visualize the variable f_1 that is a symbolic tensor?

Answer (score 0):

`Symbolic Tensors` doesn't hold values like regular tensors which we define using `tf.constant(4)` etc which you can see only the type of Tensor but you can't visualize symbolic tensors.

Usually, symbolic tensors are created while defining the model using `Functional` or `Sequential API` which means no values are explicitly defined in the network instead a framework is created for the variables to be read by the network.